# JAVA Trying to run the sleep method within the runnable object put into the new thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to make a thread sleep from within the run() method of the class i  am using in the thread i am creating thus having the thread sleep when its called and i am receiving and error from eclipse. The objective is just to test out the code several times and see that the threads output at different times as i know choosing threads to run is not a decided thing.

my code is as follows

```
    package multithreading;

    public class Mainclass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            run work= new run();

            Thread thread = new Thread(work);

            thread.start();

            System.out.println("main thread is running");

        }// end of main

    }// end of class mainclass
```

down here is the run class that i am creating an instance/object of in main up above

```
public class Run implements Runnable{// this is the beggining of the class

    public void run(){

        try {   
             thread.sleep(200); 
        }catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
        System.out.println("the second thread is running");
    }// end of run method of the class run
}// end of class run
```

any help would be greatly appreaciated

Comment: Have you ever heard about [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)? Class names should start with capital letters like in your case `MainClass`. This way it is easier to see if we are dealing with class/constructor or with variable/method.

Comment: *"and i am receiving and error from eclipse"*.  Well perhaps you should share that error message with us ...

Comment: The `thread` variable in your `main()` method is a local variable, and not in the scope of the `run()` method in your `Runnable` implementation. Also, `Thread.sleep()` is a static method; it always sleeps the current thread (the thread that invokes `sleep()`), even if you invoke it through an instance (which works, but is bad style... as is your neglect of Java naming conventions).

Answer (score 7):

`sleep` is a `static` method of `Thread`.  Java is case sensitive.

Try using `Thread.sleep` instead of `thread.sleep`

Comment: Thanks it works! that was the most straight forward helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your problem is a simple Java compilation error, and easily fixed; see @MadProgrammer's Answer,

For what it is worth, you should not be using `sleep` to get things to run before or after other things.  It is not reliable, and is liable to read to (inefficient) polling, or laggyness, or both.

There are better ways to make one thread to wait for something else to happen ... depending on what it is that you are really trying to do.